# Bootstrap-vue grid system layout is not working

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I want to use the class of layout(class 'bv-example-row')
but 'bv-example-row' class is not working in grid system.
another class of bootstrap-vue is worked well.

```
<b-container class="bv-example-row">
  <b-row>
    <b-col>1 of 3</b-col>
    <b-col>2 of 3</b-col>
    <b-col>3 of 3</b-col>
  </b-row>
</b-container>`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the example class only for documentation because It's not present in bootstrap.css and as well as in bootstrap-vue.css.

Comment: i confused because another example is working well.
thank you for your mention.

Comment: Class `bv-example-row` is only used to give the example rows/columns a background color in the documentation. Otherwise you wouldn't see where the columns sit. Rows and columns have a transparent background by default

Comment: Anyone has an idea on what `bv-example-row` might be ?